# there exist $x,y$ such that $p\mid x^2 +ay^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let a prime $p\ge 3$ and let $a$ such that $\gcd(a,p) = 1$. Show that there are $x,y\in\mathbb N$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$ such that $$p\mid x^2 +ay^2$$

We learned in class that for $f:\mathbb Z^\times_p \to \mathbb Z^\times_p$, defined as  $f(x)=x^2$ the image is: $$\{ a\in\mathbb Z^\times_p\ \mid \text {$a$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$} \}$$

I also know that the size of this set is exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

We can also show that $f(x) = ax$ is a bijection.

So we can get any quadratic residue (not including $0$) from $x^2$ and from $ay^2$.

I think I need to somehow utilize the Pigeonhole principle.

I'd be glad if you could help me with building this solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely this isn't true?

Comment: There are coprime $x,y$ such that $p \mid x^2 + ay^2$ if and only if $-a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Oh god, I just realized I didn't read the all question through...

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments $p\mid x^2+ay^2\iff -a$ is a quadratic residue. The reason for this:

$p\mid x^2+ay^2\iff x^2+ay^2\equiv_p0$. We can assume that $p$ doesn't divide $x$ or $y$ (since one of them being divisible by $p$ implies that $p$ divides the other aswell), so

$(xy^{-1})^2\equiv_p -a$.

A counter example is found when $p=3$ and $a=1$, i.e. the only solution for $x^2+y^2\equiv_3 0$ is $x\equiv_3 y\equiv_3 0$